# Evaluate in place annoyance

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, user-interface, input-forms

I want to use the following expression to get a string value:

```
Row[{"Enter index identifier: ", InputField[Dynamic[indexidentifier], String]}]
```

and I also want to hide the expression.  When I evaluate the expression "in place," it works properly, but it put quotation marks around the Enter ... string.

It clutters up (to me) the notebook. Can I get rid of the quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Style` with the option [`ShowStringCharacters -> False`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowStringCharacters.html) around the prompt:

```
Row[{Style["Enter index identifier: ", ShowStringCharacters -> False],
   InputField[Dynamic[indexidentifier], String]}]
```

After evaluating in place:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`TextCell`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextCell.html):

```
Row[{TextCell["Enter index identifier: "], InputField[Dynamic[indexidentifier], String]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I wasn't sure there was a way to do it.